# Increment a variable name in for loop

Tags: php, forms, loops

so I have a variable that I would like to set based on some submitted form data. On the form I have a set of fields that the user can increase the number of (that is, they can add more of the same type of field), and so I need to set the script that handles the submitted data to accomodate this.

So far this is what I have:

```
while ($i <= $totalproducts) {

       $product.$i = $_POST['product'.$i];
       $i++;

    }
```

$totalproducts holds the total number of fields. As an example, let's say I had 3 items, here's what I would like to get from the code:

```
$product1 = $_POST['product1'];
$product2 = $_POST['product2'];
$product3 = $_POST['product3'];
```

I'm sure I'm close, just can't quite slot it together...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [variable variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
while ($i <= $totalproducts) {
   $variable = 'product' . $i;

   $$variable = $_POST['product' . $i];
   $i++;
}
```

But better will be use array:

```
$products = array();
while ($i <= $totalproducts) {
   $products[$i] = $_POST['product' . $i];
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it like this

```
${$product.$i} = $_POST['product'.$i];
```

but this is bad style imo. Why don't you use an array? This is exactly what arrays are for.

Also arrays have many advantages. Want to know how many products there are? Easy, just `count()`. Want to pass the products to say another function? Easy, just pass the array and not an unknown number of variables, etc.

Comment: So should you in the form or whatever is the source of the $_POST data!

Comment: Thanks for the info - I ended up using an array, as per Pavel's answer too.